# Variable Label Depending On Which Radio Button Is Selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I have a webpage which displays a section with variable fields and labels. I am amending this page to add another radio button question.

I want the field labels to change depending on which radio button is selected without having to duplicate the entire section.

Code snippet is:

```
Template template = new Template();
template.Nvc.Add("[!YesRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("TransferISA_RadioButton", "Yes", ViewData["TransferISA_Yes"].Equals(true), new { id = "TranYes", onclick = "CheckRadioButton(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');", title = "To select 'Yes', 'No' has to be selected for a Child Trust Fund transfer in." }).ToHtmlString());
template.Nvc.Add("[!NoRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("TransferISA_RadioButton", "No", ViewData["TransferISA_No"].Equals(true), new { id = "TranNo", onclick = "CheckRadioButton(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');" }).ToHtmlString());
template.Nvc.Add("[!TranErrorMsg]", (Html.ValidationMessage("TransferISA_RadioButton") != null) ? Html.ValidationMessage("TransferISA_RadioButton").ToHtmlString() : "");
template.HtmlTemplate = cmsText.Text;
template.Nvc.Add("[!CTFYesRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("CTF_RadioButton", "Yes", ViewData["CTF_Yes"].Equals(true), new { id = "CTFYes", onclick = "CheckRadioButton(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');", title = "To select 'Yes', 'No' has to be selected for a Junior ISA transfer in." }).ToHtmlString());
template.Nvc.Add("[!CTFNoRadioButton]", Html.RadioButton("CTF_RadioButton", "No", ViewData["CTF_No"].Equals(true), new { id = "CTFNo", onclick = "CheckRadioButton(this,'TransferIsa_Cell','No');", }).ToHtmlString());
template.Nvc.Add("[!CTFErrorMsg]", (Html.ValidationMessage("CTF_RadioButton") != null) ? Html.ValidationMessage("CTF_RadioButton").ToHtmlString() : "");

var label1 = ***SOMETHING GOES HERE*** ? "name1" : "name2"; %>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Scripts/Application.js")%>"></script>

<%using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
  { %>
    <h1><%=cmsText.Title %></h1>

    <%=template.ToString() %>        

<div  id="TransferIsa_Cell" style="display:<%=ViewData["ISADisplay"]%>;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <h3>Current ISA manager details</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 control-label" for="CurrentManager_TextBox"><%= label1 %></label>
```

The template section is used for my CMS placeholders. I need to come up with a way to make **label1** a variable depending on the selection of the 'YesRadiobButton' and the 'CTFYesRadiobButton'.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

I've tried the following without any success:

```
    var label1 = ViewData["TransferISA_Yes"].Equals(true) ? "name1" : "name2";

    var label1 = ViewData["TransferISA_Yes"] == "true" ? "name1" : "name2";
```

Don't really want to use Java/Jquery if I can help it but if I have to I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply @krilovich but the powers be have no decided to only have one set of fields labels so this question is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - This answer only applies if your radio button is on the same page

If the elements you want data from are on the same page as the label then you shouldn't really be using ViewData.. that is more for passing something from the controller to the view

jQuery is your best option here I think

```
$('input:radio[name=nameofradiobutton]').on('change', function()
{
   var selection = $(this).val();
   if(selection == something)
   {
     $("label[for='CurrentManager_TextBox']").text("some text");
   }
});
```